# Recommend an App to capture coordinates inside an Image

Tags: image, coordinates

Can anyone recommend an Application, preferably for Mac, that will capture pixel coordinates inside an image?

Let me give some details.....

I need a quick way to capture multiple points/pixel locations within an image to a text file so that I can copy and past into IOS code. I have searched high and low and found the perfect solution. [MouseClickRecorder](http://grozi.calit2.net/) Its a Java app but the Output is not as pixels so I can't really do anything with them.

I also thought of looking at scripting it in Photoshop but I don't have the time to learn how to do that.

I am hoping that someone might have some fantastic ideas that will save me lots of time :-)

Currently I am loading the image into Photoshop and using the info pane to get the x & y coordinates then writing them down...... There MUST be an easier way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this wondering how this turned out. I ended up writing a small script in flash that handled this fantastically and even wrote out the code for me.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickPoint);
function clickPoint(event:MouseEvent):void {
trace("[points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(" + stage.mouseX + "," + stage.mouseY + ")]];");
}
```

This writes the code to the console and then I just have to copy and paste the full code into xCode.

Simple